# How to put padding around image in React-Native?

Tags: image, react-native

I have a list that will display a certain number of images in a row. What I want is for there to be space between each image. I was trying to use padding but it has not worked.

Here is what I have:

```
class ImageList extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
    require('./images/ex1.jpg'), require('./images/ex2.jpg'), require('./images/ex3.jpg')
  ])
};


}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Image source={rowData} style={styles.imageSize}/>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageSize: {

//newWidth is the width of the device divided by 4. 
//This is so that four images will display in each row. 
    width: newWidth,
    height: newWidth,
    padding: 2
  },
  list: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }
});
```

In the main file the code is called:

```
class Main extends Component {

 render(){
    return(

  <ScrollView>

  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     <View>
      <ImageList/>
     </View>
  </View>

  </ScrollView>
);
  }
};
```

I have tried putting padding in each View that I have to see if any it works. But so far nothing is working.

I have wrapped the rawData with a view like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ListView automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={{padding: 1}}><Image source={rowData} style={styles.imageSize}/></View>}
    />
  </View>
```

But this has caused a problem. When I try to have more than 3 images, only the first 3 appear. The rest are nowhere to be found.

Comment: You should wrap all the 4 images in a View. Set paddingLeft except for the first image.

Comment: I have the images wrapped in Views and I have added padding to them but nothing works. I updated my question to show more of the code I have.

Comment: I meant a View for each row of the ListView. So rowData should have something like {image1, image2, image3, image4}. Or if you want something generic. {images: []}. In your case, each row will have an image.

Comment: Could you show an example?